# How to configure server-side filtering in tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, ajax, filtering, server-side, tablesorter

I'm using the [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/) jQuery plugin with the filter widget, and I'd like to offload the actual filtering to the server. I see that there's a `filter_serversideFiltering` option for the widget, but I can't find any documentation or examples on how to set it up.

I assume I need to provide at least a URL for sending AJAX requests and a callback to handle the response, but the filter widget docs don't seem to explain where or how to do this.

(Note: I'm not using the Pager plugin here, just the filter widget. If server-side fitering is dependent on the pager for its AJAX settings, this too is not documented.)

Comment: This is all I could find: http://aplia.com/media/jsframeworks/jquery/plugins/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html
I think you'll probably have to setup a column as a filter, open the console and see what headers get sent out.

Comment: @DevlshOne That page has documentation for an older version of my fork of tablesorter. Here is [the current filter documentation page](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `filter_serversideFiltering` option does is allow integration with the pager widget/addon and prevent hiding any rows in the table if the content doesn't match.

Without the pager widget/addon you'll need to bind to the `filterEnd` event and perform your own ajax call. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uwZc2/15/) using filltext.com to provide JSON data, so the results will not match the filter, but you can see it updates after filtering. You can look at the console network tab to see the actual URL being used.

HTML

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First</th>
            <th>Last</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    var $table = $('table'),
        lastSearch = [],
        updateAjax = function (filters) {
            $.getJSON('http://www.filltext.com/?callback=?', {

                // add the current filters to be serialized
                // into a URL query string
                // commented out here or filltext.com returns nothing
                // 'filter': filters

                // the following parameters are needed for
                // filltext.com to return content
                'rows': 10,
                 '#': '{index}',
                 'ID': '{randomNumberLength|3}',
                 'First': '{firstName}',
                 'Last': '{lastName}',
                 'State': '{usState|abbr}',
                 'Info': '{lorem|3}'
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                buildTable(data);
            });
        },
        buildTable = function (data) {
            if (data) {
                var col, row, txt,
                headers = ['#', 'ID', 'First', 'Last', 'State', 'Info'],
                    len = headers.length,
                    rows = '';
                size = data.length;
                for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
                    rows += '<tr>';
                    for (col = 0; col < len; col++) {
                        txt = data[row][headers[col]];
                        rows += '<td>' + txt + '</td>';
                    }
                    rows += '</tr>';
                }

                $table.find('tbody')
                    .html(rows)
                    .trigger('update');
            }
        };

    $table.on('filterEnd', function (e, c) {
        // prevent ajax spamming
        var ls = c.$table.data('lastSearch');
        if (lastSearch.join('-') !== ls.join('-') ) {
            lastSearch = ls;
            updateAjax(lastSearch);
        }
    })
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            // prevents rows from getting hidden
            filter_serversideFiltering: true
        }
    });

});
```